# RVM 1.0.2 fails to build ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-1.9, rvm

This fails every time. I ran `rvm remove 1.9.2` and then `rvm install 1.9.2.`
The error looks like this:

```
info: Applying patch '' (located at /)

error: Error running 'patch -F25 -p1 -f <"/"', 
       please check /Users/peter/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/patch.apply.*.log

fail: There has been an error applying the specified patches. 
      Aborting the installation.
```

And the log shows this:

```
[2010-09-05 19:38:14] patch -F25 -p1 -f <"/"
patch: **** read error : Is a directory
```

This worked fine with rvm 1.0.1.

Any idea what's up and how I can roll back rvm to 1.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

For me, simply running `rvm update` (without `--head`) let Ruby 1.9.2 install right.